# How to make many to many relationship in Golang application with GORM library?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I use [GORM](http://gorm.io/) library in my **Golang** project and I need help.

In my **PostgreSQL** database I have 4 table. They called: `surveys`, `questions`, `options` and `surveys_questions_options`. Thats how they looks like:

**SURVEYS** table:

```
| survey_id (uuid4)                    | survey_name (varchar) |
|--------------------------------------|-----------------------|
| 0cf1cf18-d5fd-474e-a8be-754fbdc89720 | April                 |
| b9fg55d9-n5fy-s7fe-s5bh-856fbdc89720 | May                   |
```

**QUESTIONS** table:

```
| question_id (int) | question_text (text)         |
|-------------------|------------------------------|
| 1                 | What is your favorite color? |
```

**OPTIONS** table:

```
| option_id (int)   | option_text (text) |
|-------------------|--------------------|
| 1                 | red                |
| 2                 | blue               |
| 3                 | grey               |
| 4                 | green              |
| 5                 | brown              |
```

**SURVEYS_QUESTIONS_OPTIONS** table combines all three previous tables:

```
| survey_id                            | question_id | option_id |
|--------------------------------------|-------------|-----------|
| 0cf1cf18-d5fd-474e-a8be-754fbdc89720 | 1           | 1         |
| 0cf1cf18-d5fd-474e-a8be-754fbdc89720 | 1           | 2         |
| 0cf1cf18-d5fd-474e-a8be-754fbdc89720 | 1           | 3         |
| b9fg55d9-n5fy-s7fe-s5bh-856fbdc89720 | 1           | 3         |
| b9fg55d9-n5fy-s7fe-s5bh-856fbdc89720 | 1           | 4         |
| b9fg55d9-n5fy-s7fe-s5bh-856fbdc89720 | 1           | 5         |
```

I create struct to first 3 table and CRUD for each of table. Unfortunatly I don't know how correctly initialize many to many relationship in Golang application which you can notice in last `SURVEYS_QUESTIONS_OPTIONS` table. In fact I need to take tree JSON structure in response of REST service like:

```
[
    {
        "survey_id": "0cf1cf18-d5fd-474e-a8be-754fbdc89720",
        "survey_name": "April",
        "questions": [
            {
                "question_id": 1,
                "question_text": "What is your favorite color?",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "option_id": 1,
                        "option_text": "red"
                    },
                    {
                        "option_id": 2,
                        "option_text": "blue"
                    },
                    {
                        "option_id": 3,
                        "option_text": "grey"
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "survey_id": "b9fg55d9-n5fy-s7fe-s5bh-856fbdc89720",
        "survey_name": "May",
        "questions": [
            {
                "question_id": 1,
                "question_text": "What is your favorite color?",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "option_id": 3,
                        "option_text": "grey"
                    },
                    {
                        "option_id": 4,
                        "option_text": "green"
                    },
                    {
                        "option_id": 5,
                        "option_text": "brown"
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Can someone show me how to make it by little example?

Comment: Please stop rolling back (rejecting) valid edits. The user who suggested these edits has already explained clearly that the [[tag:gorm]] tag is used for the Rails library, and that is also quite obvious from reading the tag description. The [[tag:go-gorm]] tag is the one you want, and that's exactly the one which was added to this question in the edits. Getting into an edit war serves no one. If you have a problem, either take it to Meta or flag for moderator attention.